# Хорошо ли использовать передачу переменных по ссылке?

Tags: php

Вопрос о читабельности кода и использовании в большом продукте.

Хорошо ли работать с переменными по ссылке, не убивает ли это читабельность кода ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала, зачем может понадобится передавать значение по ссылке:

- ради производительности и экономии памяти, из-за отсутствия копирования значения. *Не имеет смысла в PHP.* Переменные в PHP передаются в стиле copy-on-write (и известное исключение - объекты и ресурсы, которые всегда передаются по ссылке). Если в функции вы будете значение только читать - реального копирования выполнено не будет. В PHP7 некоторые скаляры стали передаваться вновь по значению, но из-за необходимости создавать новый zval (базовая структура переменной), куда и встроили значения этих скаляров - это не ухудшает потребление памяти и других ресурсов. То, для чего реально можно использовать передачу по ссылке - массивные структуры данных - и так не копируются реально. Это же касается и `$a = $b;`. Если в $b был объёмный массив, вы не получите два объёмных массива - вы получите две ссылки на один массив. И только если вы попробуете изменить $a или $b, то будет выполнено копирование данных.
- ради изменения значения этой переменной. Побочный эффект, часто не очевидный без анализа кода самой функции или как-минимум просмотра объявления функции. Процитирую книгу Роберта Мартина, "Чистый код":

> Аргументы естественным образом интерпретируются как входные данные функции. ... Пример:
>   appendFooter(s);
>   Присоединяет ли эта функция s в качестве завершающего блока к чему-то другому? Или она присоединяет какой-то завершающий блок к s? Является ли s входным или выходным аргументом? Конечно, можно посмотреть сигнатуру и получить ответ. Вопрос снимается, но только после проверки объявления. Всё, что заставляет обращаться к сигнатуре функции, нарушает естественный ритм чтения кода. Подобных "повторных заходов" следует избегать.

Поэтому - не надо использовать передачу по ссылке без серьёзных на то причин. А имея такие причины - подберите явное и непротиворечивое имя функции, которое будет сразу говорить, что эта функция изменяет переданный аргумент.